# GetMethodID failes on android jni

Tags: android, callback, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implement a callback function in JNI/NDK.
I got error in GetMethodID function

I want to execute a function in Java (from C) that has the following signature:

[java code]

```
public int callback(String msg) {
    cb_tv.setText(msg);
    return 1;
}
```

[native C code]

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni1_nativeJava_testDirectCallback(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj) {
    static jmethodID cb = NULL;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);

    if(cb == NULL)  {
        cb = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I");
    if(cb == NULL) return;
    }
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, cb, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "[C->J] callback"));

    return;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
08-01 16:26:43.617: W/dalvikvm(516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-01 16:26:43.637: E/AndroidRuntime(516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 16:26:43.637: E/AndroidRuntime(516): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: callback
```

---

I don't understand the error.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you confirm that the `callback()` method is in the same class as `Java_com_example_hellojni1_nativeJava_testDirectCallback`?  And further, that `Java_com_example_hellojni1_nativeJava_testDirectCallback` is declared "native" and not "static native"?  I see that the second argument is `jclass` rather than `jobject`... if it's actually a `jclass`, then `GetObjectClass` is going to return a reference to `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Not related to your question but...to safely cache method Ids see this standard JNI [advice](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) from Android.

Comment: You're sharp very well!! I spent several days. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like fadden metioned...

Check that your Java_com_example_hellojni1_nativeJava_testDirectCallback is declared "native" and not "static native".

This was my problem.